# invoke methods which are elements of an array

Tags: ruby

```
class Shop
  def self.name
    "kids-toy"
  end

  def self.postcode
    1000
  end
end

methods = ["name", "postcode"]
methods.each {|m|
  mcall = "Shop.#{m}"
  eval mcall
}
```

Is there any other way rather than calling `eval` to invoke methods which are elements of an array?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, possible using [`Method#call`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Method.html#method-i-call) method :

```
class Shop
  def self.name
    "kids-toy"
  end

  def self.postcode
    1000
  end
end

methods = ["name", "postcode"]
methods.each do |m|
  p Shop.method(m).call
end

# >> "kids-toy"
# >>  1000
```

`Shop.method(m)` will give you an object of the class [`Method`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Method.html), now you can invoke the method `#call` on that method object.

Answer (score 5):

Using [Object#send](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Object.html#method-i-send):

```
methods.each { |m| Shop.send(m) }
```

Comment: Or use `public_send` to avoid breaking encapsulation, if you think that might be an issue.